# How to build project dependency before building main Maven project from command line automatically without using 3rd multi module maven project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have 2 Maven projects, Project B will be a dependency inside Project A. I want to build Project A from command line with "mvn clean install", but to have dependent Project B built automatically(so Project B needs to be built before Project A, like I am running "`mvn clean install`" first on Project B then the same on Project A)

I have tried running "`mvn clean install`" on Project A but it gives me error that it cannot find Project B jar file. If I run "`mvn clean install`" first on Project B, then on Project A, everything works fine. But i want it to be automatically built, so the Project B is built before Project A, as it's a dependency on Project A.

I expected that "`mvn clean install`" first build Project B as A is dependent on B, then Project A itself.
The output is -

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:projectA:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example:projectB:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: My opinion is that if the projects are so tightly coupled that they always need to be built at the same time, maybe it should be 1 project with 2 submodules.
If they are not so tightly coupled, then maybe one project should have a fix version dependency on another project so they can be built (and deployed) separately. BTW: do you use any CI build server, there it may be possible to have a dependency? Or via a script (even if that's not pretty).

Comment: Unless explicitly told, Maven will not know of A when working with B and vice versa.  You either need some glue tying A and B together or live with knowing you have a dependency.

Comment: @helospark Yes i am using Jenkins. But in the end i wrote a script which builds projects in desired order.

Answer (score 2):

Different possible approaches:

1. Create a multi-module project (from your headline I understand that you do not want that).
2. Create an aggregator project with a pom that builds both projects.
3. Write a shell script that calls both `mvn clean install` commands in the right order.